# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments which have right number and type

Tags: oracle, debugging, plsql, procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE REC_PURGE
(
  pInterfaceName              IN    VARCHAR2,
  pInterfaceRunDate           IN    VARCHAR2,        -- MM/DD/YYYY
  PARAM_CLEANUP_DAYS          IN    NUMBER,
  pErrorCd                    OUT   NUMBER
)
AS

--************************************************************************************************************
--**                      DECLARE LOCAL VARIABLES                                                           **
--************************************************************************************************************/
  LV_CLEANUP_DAYS                     NUMBER        := 366; 
  LV_SP_RUN_DT                        VARCHAR2(19)  := pInterfaceRunDate; 
  lv_interdaceRunDate                 TIMESTAMP     := TO_DATE(pInterfaceRunDate,'MM/DD/YYYY');

BEGIN


IF PARAM_CLEANUP_DAYS IS NOT NULL THEN
  LV_CLEANUP_DAYS := PARAM_CLEANUP_DAYS;
END IF;

DELETE /*+ PARALLEL(16) */
from ST_DTI_MBR_STG
where rec_lst_updt_dttm <= trunc(TO_DATE(LV_SP_RUN_DT,'MM/DD/YYYY')-LV_CLEANUP_DAYS);

COMMIT;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        pErrorCd:= SQLCODE;
        pErrorMsg := 'Failure at step ' || TO_CHAR(lvCurrentStep, '99.90') || ' with the message: ' || SQLCODE || '-' || SQLERRM;

END REC_PURGE;
```

Here's the code how I create the procedure, and i rxc it like this:

```
DECLARE
  PINTERFACENAME VARCHAR2(200);
  PINTERFACERUNDATE VARCHAR2(19);
  PARAM_CLEANUP_RANGE NUMBER;
  PERRORCD NUMBER;
BEGIN
  PINTERFACENAME :='REC';
  PINTERFACERUNDATE := '03/18/2020';
  PARAM_CLEANUP_RANGE := '366';

  REC_PURGE(
    PINTERFACENAME => PINTERFACENAME,
    PINTERFACERUNDATE => PINTERFACERUNDATE,
    PARAM_CLEANUP_RANGE => PARAM_CLEANUP_RANGE,
    PERRORCD => PERRORCD
  );
  PERRORCD := PERRORCD;
END;
```

The type and number is match but i still get error

> ```
> ORA-06550: line 11, column 3:
> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'REC_PURGE'
> ORA-06550: line 11, column 3:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored
> ```

Do anyone have any idea why?

Comment: The name of the third parameter is `PARAM_CLEANUP_DAYS`, but when calling the procedure you wrote `PARAM_CLEANUP_RANGE`. (The error message is a bit misleading since it is not the number or types of the args that is incorrect.)

Comment: Clearly you modified the code between when you got that error and when you posted it here. The procedure you posted will throw an error when you try to compile it, long before you get to call it from another block. That's because in the error handling section you invoke a variable you never defined, `pErrorMsg`. So, how can we take anything you say seriously?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP clearly didn't get the error he reports from the code he posted. Can't be taken seriously.

Comment: there some important info need to hide, but it is not relate to the error, i tried remove them and still got same error.

Comment: @Lodye Did you try what i posted below.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are declaring a `Varchar` to hold a date. Use `DATE` variable to hold a date as shown below:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE st_dti_mbr_stg
  ( col NUMBER,rec_lst_updt_dttm TIMESTAMP
  );

 SELECT * FROM st_dti_mbr_stg;

 INSERT INTO st_dti_mbr_stg  VALUES   (1,sysdate );
 INSERT INTO st_dti_mbr_stg  VALUES   (1,sysdate-60 );
```

Procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE REC_PURGE
(
  pInterfaceName              IN    VARCHAR2,
  pInterfaceRunDate           IN    DATE,-- VARCHAR2,    --<-- Use Date variable
  PARAM_CLEANUP_DAYS          IN    NUMBER,
  pErrorCd                    OUT   NUMBER
)
AS

--************************************************************************************************************
--**                      DECLARE LOCAL VARIABLES                                                           **
--************************************************************************************************************/
  LV_CLEANUP_DAYS                     NUMBER        := 366; 
 -- LV_SP_RUN_DT                        VARCHAR2(19)  := pInterfaceRunDate; 
  LV_SP_RUN_DT                        DATE       := pInterfaceRunDate; 
  --lv_interdaceRunDate                 TIMESTAMP     := TO_DATE(pInterfaceRunDate,'MM/DD/YYYY');

BEGIN

IF PARAM_CLEANUP_DAYS IS NOT NULL 
THEN
  LV_CLEANUP_DAYS := PARAM_CLEANUP_DAYS;
END IF;

dbms_output.put_line(LV_SP_RUN_DT || '  '||LV_CLEANUP_DAYS);

DELETE /*+ PARALLEL(16) */
from ST_DTI_MBR_STG
where trunc(rec_lst_updt_dttm) <= LV_SP_RUN_DT - LV_CLEANUP_DAYS;

COMMIT;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        pErrorCd:= SQLCODE;
       -- pErrorMsg := 'Failure at step ';-- || TO_CHAR(lvCurrentStep, '99.90') || ' with the message: ' || SQLCODE || '-' || SQLERRM;

END REC_PURGE;
```

---

Execution;

```
DECLARE
  PINTERFACENAME VARCHAR2(200);
  PINTERFACERUNDATE DATE ;--VARCHAR2(19);
  PARAM_CLEANUP_RANGE NUMBER;
  PERRORCD NUMBER;
BEGIN
  PINTERFACENAME :='REC';
  PINTERFACERUNDATE :=to_Date('03/18/2020','MM/DD/YYYY');
  PARAM_CLEANUP_RANGE := 30;

  REC_PURGE(
    pInterfaceName => PINTERFACENAME,
    pInterfaceRunDate => PINTERFACERUNDATE,
    PARAM_CLEANUP_DAYS => PARAM_CLEANUP_RANGE, --<- You messed up argument name
    pErrorCd => PERRORCD
  );
  PERRORCD := PERRORCD;
END;
```